# Error sending data by axios.post () and receiving it within a function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, axios

I sent a data in axios.post () to a function in Node.js. The function didn't accept all the parameters of the data.
What's my mistake ??

This is the code in React:

```
            axois.post('http://localhost:9000/question/create', **question**)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('res.data -> ', res.data);  // The res.data sends all the data (see it in the console)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('error -> ', error);
            });
```

This is the code in Node.js:

````
    console.log('req -> ', req.body); // The req.body didn't get all the parameters of the data that came to it.
  dataQuestion.create(**req.body**, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
          return next(error)
      } else {
          console.log(data)
          res.json(data)
      }
  });
}); ```

Appreciates any answer ...
Thank you!
````

Answer (score 0):

performing a post with axios, you need a second param which is the body of the post request

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```